# OpenCV Video Feed Automatic Resizing with PyQt5

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

this is my first post on Stack Overflow so I hope I'm doing everything correctly.

I have been trying to get a video feed using OpenCV on a GUI made using PyQt5. I eventually got this to work, but it is always 640 x 480 (the size I set it to). However, I want it to automatically scale/resize (with the same aspect ratio) to fit within its parenting widget. For example, when I expand the window, the video feed should scale, too. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Here is a sample of my code for reference:

**Camera Widget**

```py
class Camera(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, port):
        super().__init__()

        self.display_width = 640
        self.display_height = 480


        self.camera = QLabel(self)
        self.camera.resize(self.display_width, self.display_height)

        self.label = QLabel(f'Port {port}')

        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                color: white;
                font: bold 30px
            }
        """)

        # Layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.camera)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.thread = VideoThread(port)
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.thread.start()

    def close_event(self, event):
        self.thread.stop()
        event.accept()

    @pyqtSlot(ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.camera.setPixmap(qt_img)

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.display_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)
```

**Video feed Thread**

```py
class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(ndarray)

    def __init__(self, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.port)
        
        while self.running:
            self.ret, self.image = self.capture.read()
            if self.ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(self.image)

        self.capture.release()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.wait()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the resize event of `self.camera` and set it's width to `self.display_width` and it's height to `self.display_height`

and this statement `p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.display_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)`  will do the rest of the work

---

### Update

Set the Minimum size to avoid recursive loop which will keep expanding window

To avoid **shaking** you can use a `fixed size container` or remove `Qt.KeepAspectRatio` which helps shaking the window

- HERE IS THE UPDATED CODE

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from numpy import ndarray



class Camera(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, port):
        super().__init__()

        self.display_width = 640
        self.display_height = 480


        self.camera = QLabel()
        # self.camera.setGeometry(0,0,640,480)
        self.camera.resize(self.display_width, self.display_height)
        
        #  Set Minimum size of camera stream to avoid going in recursive loop
        self.camera.setMinimumWidth(640)
        self.camera.setMinimumHeight(480)

        self.label = QLabel(f'Port {port}')

        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
                color: black;
                font: 30px;
        """)

        # Layout

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.camera)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Get the resize Event Callback
        self.resizeEvent = self.label_resize
        self.camera.resizeEvent = self.camera_resize

        self.thread = VideoThread(port)
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.thread.start()

    # Resize Event Callback
    def label_resize(self, resizeEvent:QResizeEvent):
        self.camera.resize(resizeEvent.size())

    # Resize Event Callback
    def camera_resize(self, resizeEvent:QResizeEvent):
        self.display_width, self.display_height = self.camera.width(), self.camera.height()


    def close_event(self, event):
        self.thread.stop()
        event.accept()

    @pyqtSlot(ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.camera.setPixmap(qt_img)

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.display_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(ndarray)

    def __init__(self, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.port)

        while self.running:
            self.ret, self.image = self.capture.read()
            if self.ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(self.image)

        self.capture.release()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.wait()
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. `self.label` is just a label that shows the port that `self.camera` is on. Even removing the label entirely doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your response. I added in a `resizeEvent` which updates `self.display_width` and `self.display_height`, but all it does is gradually increase the camera size without me doing anything.

Comment: my mistake.. get the resize event of `self.camera` and set its width and height to `self.display_width` and `self.display_height`

Comment: You need to get the resize event of window and and on resize change size of camera label.. which will eventually resize the camera stream

Comment: I added `self.camera.setFixedWidth(self.display_width)` and `self.camera.setFixedHeight(self.display_height)` in a `resizeEvent`, but it still doesn't change the size.

Comment: Don't use `setFixedWidth` or `setFixedHeight` if you plan to resize it..

Comment: My bad, I replaced it with `resize`. But instead of resizing, it just starts shaking when I try to resize the window.

Comment: Edited Answer You can check it if it helps.. @ChickwensRule

Comment: Only thing is that if I put two `Camera`s in a `QGridLayout`, one of the cameras is sometimes bigger than the other. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Nevermind, I found that it was because the two cameras were added after each other, which is why scaling broke sometimes.